# How do I hide a card with bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4

So I am trying to hide a bootstrap card on xs screens only. I have tried hiding on all screen sizes to test my code, it has not worked on them either.

...

```
<div class"container">
<div class="d-none d-sm-block">
<div class="card">
<p style="padding:5px">Meet the Club</p>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">     
<figure class="figure">...
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you post a minimal example but you can use

```
    .d-none .d-sm-block
```

on the same element (in this case you can add it to card class or the containing div) to hide something in xs screens

Answer (score 0):

as mentionned in the comments, there is a way to do so using bootstrap :
`.d-none .d-sm-block`. I do see in your example that you included this class already. perhaps your version of bootstrap is older and doesn't include the display (`d-*`) helpers. I would try using the `.visible-xs-*` methods, available on bootstrap 3 (couldn't find it for version 2)

alternatively, you could use @media for the xs screen size (you can find it easily by searching bootstrap screen size, for xs it is 576px) then use `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` on your element

Ex:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px){
    .elementClass{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Bootstrap has already built in this functionality so it's more work to declare that class.